# How i want to enlarge the image by using biliner interpolation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How i want to enlarge the image by using biliner interpolation in matlab? Can u help me with the coding and the programming . i'm facing the problem to enlarge the image.

Comment: You need to demonstrate more effort than this. This isn't a place to get people to write code for you.

Comment: I'm beginner to matlab , need u give me a rough idea , not the all coding . thanks

Comment: Did you try googling "enlarge the image by using biliner interpolation in matlab"?

Comment: Here's my implementation of bilinear interpolation in MATLAB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142288/how-to-shrink-an-image-without-using-imresize-function-in-matlab/26143655#26143655

Answer (score 1):

```
img = imread('your_image.png' , 'png');  //extension can be jpg,png,...

img = im2double(img);   // convert uint8 to double

img_large = interp2(img, 'linear');   //bilinear interpolation

figure; imshow(img_large,[]);    //see your enlarged image
```

hope it helps