# Resize an image to original size after sub sampling

Tags: matlab, image-processing, subsampling

I am subsampling an image using matlab. But I have a task to reset the subsampled image to original size. I have done it with nearest neighbour approximation and averaging adjacent pixels which is working fine.Is there any other algorithm to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29766889/802378), it should work without using `imresize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, there still have least two method:

1. pixel area re-sampling
2. bicubic interpolation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: maybe this is too short?

Comment: I did Bicubic Interpolation and the output was what I expected.Thank you.

Comment: This is a ridiculously poor answer, especially when you have one here that actually shows an implementation in MATLAB.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765714/resize-an-image-to-original-size-after-sub-sampling/29766889#

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on not using the `imresize` builtin function, you can use `interp2` to rescale the image. First define a scaling factor `f`. Then you can use `interp2` to do it as follows.

```
% Toy Data
I = im2double( imread( 'bag.png' ) );

% Set Scaling Factor
f = 1/5;

% Resize Image
D = interp2( I, linspace( 1, size(I,2), size(I,2) * f ), linspace( 1, size(I,1), size(I,1) * f )' );

% Plot Image
figure; imshow( I );
figure; imshow( D );
```

To understand what this code does, first understand that this line finds the number of subdivisions within the `linspace`.

```
size(I,2) * f
```

After you create the `linspace`, you can use `interp2` for the cols for the 2nd argument and rows for the 3rd argument. The image must be a double hence the `im2double`.

If you don't wish to use `interp2` either, as @rayryeng said, you should refer to how to do it [without any builtin functions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142288/resize-an-image-with-bilinear-interpolation-without-imresize).

Comment: While this technically uses inbuild functions for interpolation, I'd assume it would qualify unless doing the interpolation itself was the task. Note that [interp2](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) also features multiple interpolation methods: 'linear', 'nearest', 'cubic' and 'spline'.

Comment: @Mathias I agree and its pretty difficult to code your own like that. I changed my answer to specify which built in function wasn't used. While `interp2` does have multiple interpolation methods, this will allow the user to choose which one they want and defaults to (iirc) the linear one.

Comment: @Mathias also I don't believe that `interp2` requires any toolbox while `imresize` requires the image toolbox which is probably what the OP likely meant

Comment: @krisdestruction - You can code bilinear interpolation without `interp2` and it's quite simple.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142288/resize-an-image-with-bilinear-interpolation-without-imresize

Comment: @rayryeng Good point, I will add that to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a basic Image resize correct?
There are several algorithms available with [description from mathworks](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html).

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reference. But I should not use matlab inbuilt function.

Comment: There are like a million resize algorithms. The most popular are Nearest Neighbour, Bilinear, Bicubic, Lanczos and Spline types. The basic is usually generating a picewise interpolation of the pixes and sampling them into a new grid. I'd advise just searching for these algorithms and maybe post a new question, based on that.