# Setting Table Values using Loops with Index Vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've a series of coordinates (i,j) and I want to loop through each one.

For example

```
A = ones(3,3);
i = [1 2 3];
j = [3 2 1];
```

I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
for (i = i && j = j)
   A(i,j) = 0;
end
```

I also tried this but it doens't work as expected:

```
for i = i
    for j = j
        A(i,j) = 0;
    end
end
```

Desired result:

```
A =
1 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
```

Although `A` is a matrix in this example, I am working with table data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax to do what you want is:

```
A = ones(3,3);
i = [1 2 3];
j = [3 2 1];

for ii = 1:length( i )
    A( i(ii) , j(ii) ) = 0;
end
```

Essentially you loop through each element and index `i` and `j` accordingly using `ii`. `ii` loops through 1..3 indexing each element.

This will give the a final result below.

```
>> A
A =
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     1     1
```

While this works and fixes your issue, I would recommend [rayryeng's alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833962/802378) with conversions if you don't have more complex operations involved.

Comment: @mat If this is your preferred solution, please kindly accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Though this doesn't answer your question about `for` loops, I would avoid using loops all together and create column-major linear indices to access into your matrix.  Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to help facilitate that.  `sub2ind` takes in the size of the matrix in question, the row locations and column locations.  The output will be an array of values that specify the column-major locations to access in your matrix.

Therefore:

```
A = ones(3); i = [1 2 3]; j = [3 2 1]; %// Your code
%// New code
ind = sub2ind(size(A), i, j);
A(ind) = 0;
```

---

Given that you have a table, you can perhaps convert the table into an array, apply `sub2ind` on this array then convert the result back to a table when you're done.  [`table2array`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html) and [`array2table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) are useful tools here.  Given that your table is stored in `A`, you can try:

```
Atemp = table2array(A);
ind = sub2ind(size(Atemp), i, j);
Atemp(ind) = 0;
A = array2table(Atemp);
```

Comment: Agree with the `sub2ind` and I recommend this solution, unless you have some more complex operation involved. +1

Comment: I like this solution. However, in my script A is a table, so I cannot use linear indices.

Comment: Gotta start learning `sub2ind`. I've seen it multiple times but have never gotten used to using it >.<

Comment: @krisdestruction - Thanks :) I +1ed you too as you fundamentally found what was wrong with the original method.

Comment: @krisdestruction - It's actually very easy.  If you read the post on that bilinear interpolation stuff without `interp2`, I give a brief tutorial on what it's about. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142288/resize-an-image-with-bilinear-interpolation-without-imresize/26143655#26143655

Comment: @mat - I thought it was a matrix.  If I knew it was a table, I would have not suggested this answer.  You need to tell me the whole story!

Comment: @rayryeng Is there a way to use `sub2ind` even with a table? I assume with a few conversions, it would work. Thanks for the link, I'll look at it when I have spare time!

Comment: @krisdestruction - Yes... though it's very hackish.  You can convert the table to an array, perform `sub2ind`, then convert back to a table... so `table2array`, then `sub2ind` then `array2table`.

Comment: @krisdestruction - I've added in how to accommodate for tables to make it complete.  BTW, you're welcome for the link :) You can ignore the fluff about the interpolation bit.  Just read the part where I talk about `sub2ind`.