# Index in position __ exceeds array bounds

Tags: matlab, image-processing, indexing, translation

Having Trouble with this Error "Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values." It only occurs when I enter certain values for the translation. Such as -25 x-direction and +50 in the y-direction. But it will work if I enter in any decimal values such as (12.75,-19.3).  Please help me out.

Note: A is an imported image

````
if (delta_x == 0 && delta_y == 0) % Allows the Orginal Image to be displayed
    figure(1)
    image(0:ynew-1,0:xnew-1,A) % display a matrix as an image
    axis equal
    axis ij  % put 0,0 in UL corner
    axis tight
    colormap(gray(L)) % use an 8-bit grayscale 
    xlabel('y')
    ylabel('x')
    title('Original Image')
    return
end

%Translation Matrix 3x3
Trans = [1 0 delta_x; 0 1 delta_y; 0 0 1];
InverseTrans = (inv(Trans)); %Inverse Mapping Begins

%Allocate Space
E = zeros(xnew, ynew,k);

for i=1:xold
    for j=1:yold
        % matrix math assumes origin is (0,0) not (1,1)
        vw=InverseTrans*[i; j; 1]; % vw will be [v; w; 1]
        v = vw(1);
        w = vw(2);
        if (v < 0 || v >(xold-1))  % Testing for Out of Bounds
            E(i,j) = 0;
        elseif (w < 0 || w >(yold-1)) % Testing for out of Bounds
            E(i,j) = 0;
        else 

%Takes the Real INTEGER Part 
v_fix = fix(v);
w_fix = fix(w);

v_fix1 = v_fix +1;%Indexing
w_fix1 = w_fix +1;


%Change in the Values
dX = v - v_fix;
dY = w - w_fix;

%Indexing Purposes            **This is where I'm getting my error**
D1(i,j) = A(v_fix1, w_fix1);
D2(i,j) = A(v_fix1 + 1, w_fix1);
D3(i,j) = A(v_fix1, w_fix1 + 1);
D4(i,j) = A(v_fix1 + 1, w_fix1 + 1);



        end
    end
end```
````

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use [`dbstop if error`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buzezti-1).

Comment: Yeah its On D2(i,j) but not quite sure how to fix it! it only has an error if its whole numbers!

Comment: Apparently, the value of `v_fix1 + 1` is greater than the number of rows in your image. If `v` is a whole number, do you really want to interpolate `v` and `v+1`? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245959/matlab-image-rotation) (and the post linked in the answer regarding interpolation) might be helpful.